# Insert data into some columns with Zend Framework 2

Tags: sql, zend-framework, insert, zend-framework2, sql-insert

I have a problem with inserting data into some columns without modifying the others.
For example: I have `user (name , email , address)` and I would like to insert only the email value into user table. How can I do it?

```
public function insert($model) {
        $data = get_object_vars($model);
        $id = (int) $model->id;
        if ($id == 0) {
            $this->tableGateway->insert($data);
            return $this->tableGateway->lastInsertValue;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited your question. I removed the snippet part, because snippets are only for client-side executable code (in practice, JavaScript). I'm not familiar with Zend Framework, but it sounds like you need some kind of `UPDATE` statement? If not, could you please [edit] the question to explain how your problem is different from using `UPDATE`? Anyway, good luck and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 0):

make sure your `$data` is on format

```
$data = ['name'=>'abc', 'email'=>'abc@gmail.com', 'address'=>''];
```

now you want only to insert email,
then,

```
$data = ['email'=>'abc@gmail.com'];
```

for update to a particular field, use

```
$this->tableGateway->update($data, array('id' => $id));
```

Comment: when i write $this->getAddiinfoTable()->update($data); it set the value of other columns to 0 or null !!!!

Comment: if you insert a new record, then either you should provide all column values Or they will be set as default (default defined value for column)

Comment: You should set your default column value, if you wish something (special) to be inserted if data is not provided for the column

Comment: i wouldn't edit the previous  value  of name and address , i would like just update email value

Comment: $tableGateway->update(['email'=>'abc@gmail.com'], array('id' => $id));